# Представление в двоичном виде числа

Tags: c

Не могу никак понять, как сделать, чтобы в функция PrintVar выводила число в двоичном виде. При условии, что она должна делать это для любого типа.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
        /*Выводит число в двоичном виде*/
        void PrintByte(unsigned char num) {
            for(int i = 8 * sizeof(num); i > 0; i-- ) {
                printf("%d", (num & (1 << (i-1))) ? 1 : 0);
            }
        }
    /*Должна выводить число в двоичном виде*/
    void PrintVar(void *a, unsigned int size) {
             char *b = (char *)a;
             b = b + (size );
             for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
               PrintByte(*b);
               b--;
            }
            }

        int main() {
            long int u = 50;
            printf("1: ");
            PrintByte(u);


            float d = 10;
            printf("\n2: ");
            PrintVar(&d, sizeof(float));
        }
```

Comment: Так она и выводит число в двоичном виде. В памяти компьютера число лежит именно так как она его выводит. А то что это float, да он будет выглядеть стренно, ведь он в ieee754 https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в количестве выводимых байт (на один больше), и в сдвиге памяти, что выводить. А то, что вы видите не то, это про формат чисел надо почитать.

```
/*Должна выводить число в двоичном виде*/
    void PrintVar(void *a, unsigned int size) {
             char *b = (char *)a;
             b = b + (size );
             //for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
             for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
               b--;
               PrintByte(*b);
               //b--;
            }
            }
```